# Pandas assign categories to numbers in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, categories

I have this dataframe:

```
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| values_A | values_B | values_A_r | values_B_r |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|    1.623 |  1.91232 |        1.6 |     1.9123 |
|    1.582 |  1.32154 |        1.6 |     1.3215 |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to find the difference between values_A (rounded to 1 digit) and values_A_r, as well as the difference between values_B (rounded to 4 digit) and values_B_r. Assign the categories "Same", "More", or "Less" depending on the difference. If all the differences are "Same", print out a message. This is my current code.

```
def test_func():                                                         

    check['A_check'] = np.where(abs(round(check.values_A,1) - check.values_A_r)<1**-10, 'Same',
                                 np.where(round(check.values_A,1) > check.values_A_r, 'Less', 'More'))
    check['B_check'] = np.where(abs(round(check.values_B,4) - check.values_B_r)<1**-10, 'Same',
                                 np.where(round(check.values_B,4) > check.values_B_r, 'Less', 'More'))
    if (set([len(check.index)])==set([check.A_check.value_counts().Same,
                                     check.B_check.value_counts().Same])):
        return print('Correct!')
    else:
        raise SystemExit('Incorrect.')
test_func()
```

I'm currently using nested np where statements to assign the categories and it looks really messy. Additionally, I have to use <1**-10 instead of ==0 because sometimes when the numbers are the "Same", the difference is calculated to be something like 8**-12 instead of just 0.

This process seems really simple and the code makes it look complicated. Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: hi, as per my understanding, first a diff needs to taken out for both a,a_r and b,b_r and then compare both the difference and assign less, more and same based on that right ?

Comment: Calculate differences between a and a_r, assign Same, More, and Less to those differences. Do the same for b and b_r. Then check to see if all the differences were "Same". (in this case there should be a total of 4 "Same"s)

Answer (score 0):

The following let's you quickly check if the values are the same or not:

```
if ((check.values_A.round(1) - check_values_A_r).abs() < 1e-10).sum() == \
((check.values_B.round(4) - check_values_B_r).abs() < 1e-10).sum():
    print('Correct!')
else:
    raise SystemExit('Incorrect.')
```

Here we are using a handy property of boolean `pd.Series` which is that `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`. So we just check if the boolean Series which we get from comparing `A` with `A_r` and `B` with `B_r` have the same amounts of `True` values.

The following should give you your `A_check` column:

```
check['A_check'] = 'Same'
diff_A = (check.values_A.round(1) - check_values_A_r).abs()
check.loc[diff_A > 1**-10, 'A_check'] = 'More'
check.loc[diff_A < -1**-10, 'A_check'] = 'Less'
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for just A;  B is the same then:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'values_A': [1.623,1.582], 'values_A_r': [1.6,1.6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dfr = abs(round(df.values_A,1) - df.values_A_r) < 1e-10

if len(dfr.index) == dfr.agg('sum'):
   print('correct')
else:
   print('incorrect')
```